# How do I automatically inherit a foreignkey model's field in django rest?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

[image]Models.py, From django admin what I do is I can add a product to Featured but the problem is when I select a product in admin to make featured I want to automatically inherit that product's image url which was uploaded when that product was created.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True)

    image = models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class FeaturedProduct(models.Model):
    db_identification = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    featured = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    photograph = How do I inherit it automatically from foreignkey product selected?
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.db_identification
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is probably not a good idea to duplicate the image. Indeed, a database is designed to avoid data duplication. Anyway in your code, if you want the `Product` image for a given `FeaturedProduct` you can use :

```
featured_product = FeaturedProduct.object.get(...)
image = feature_product.product.image
```

This way, you have no duplication. (Easier in case of image changing for example !).

**EDIT :** If you want to easily access from FeaturedProduct, you can add a util method :

```
class FeaturedProduct(models.Model):
    db_identification = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    featured = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.db_identification

    @property
    def photograph(self):
       return self.product.image
```

Comment: when I select the foreignkey to be featured via django admin and then navigate to the featured url it should show the product which it does which I have made featured but I also want it to show the image url which is for that product automatically

Comment: You are right. It missed a util method to get it easily. I've edited my answer

Comment: can anyone help me out?

Comment: I edited my Question and added a picture of the output for selecting a product to be shown in featured but how do I inherit the image url which is already specified for that foreignkey product???

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the save function of the `FeaturedProduct`

```python
class FeaturedProduct(models.Model):
    db_identification = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    featured = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    photograph = models.FileField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.db_identification

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.photograph = self.featured.image
        super(FeaturedProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Don't you think that it is a bad practice to duplicate data ?

Comment: you're probably right :) I actually just wanted to show the principle. If I interpret the question correctly, the author of the question actually just wants to store an url anyway ...?

Comment: I don't want to duplicate anything I just want to get the image url which. was saved for the product I am trying to make featured

Comment: Than you just need to change the photograph to an UrlField and set it to the correct url in the save methode.

Comment: bro the product already has an image in the media folder and that is returned as a url, but now when I select a product as a foreignkey I want to get/inherit that selected product's image so. it comes in json when I navigate to /featured

Comment: How do i get the image url for the product selected in the view in json???

Comment: can anyone help??